# gradle build fails with RepositoryNotFoundException

Tags: git, gradle

I'm trying to build a project and I keep getting the following error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/git/project/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
> org/eclipse/jgit/errors/RepositoryNotFoundException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.969 secs
```

This happens when I attempt to load a plugin that I have uploaded to a local repository:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url uri(System.getenv('LOCAL_REPO'))
    } 
  }
}

subprojects{
  apply plugin: 'otherproject.plugin' // line 24
}
```

I called `gradle uploadArchives` from the other project to upload that plugin to the local repo, and it is being found by this project.

I've googled it and there isn't much information on this exception, but what I have found says that gradle is looking for a git repository that does not exist.  I'm not sure why gradle is looking for a git repo in this case.

What does this error actually mean, and what can cause it?  The documentation simply says "Indicates a local repository does not exist" and I can't figure anything out with that little information.  If you need more info from me, ask in the comments.  I'm totally stumped here.

Comment: Without seeing the `build.gradle` build file and stacktrace (`--stacktrace`), I don't think a specific answer can be provided.  As this is a 5 year old question, I'm going to guess you've resolved this or otherwise moved past it, and there's not much value in providing an answer here.  I'm going to vote to close this as "Needs debugging details".  If those can be provided, or if you're able to provide the explanation of why it failed in your specific case, I'll retract my close vote.